# Django database settings bad

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I do the following:

myScript.py

```
# settings.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from myApp.models import *


    settings.configure(
        DATABASE_ENGINE    = 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        DATABASE_NAME      = 'Test',
        DATABASE_USER      = 'root',
        DATABASE_PASSWORD  = 'testpw',
        DATABASE_HOST      = '/var/run/mysql',
        DATABASE_PORT      = '3306',
        INSTALLED_APPS     = ('myApp')
    )

    from django.db import models
    from myApp.models import *
```

With the following settings.py

```
DATABASE_ENGINE    = 'mysql'
DATABASE_NAME      = 'Test'
DATABASE_USER      = 'root'
DATABASE_PASSWORD  = 'testpw'
DATABASE_HOST      = '/var/run/mysql'
DATABASE_PORT      = '3306'
INSTALLED_APPS     = ('myApp')
```

I make a mistake with my settings but can not get what the error is. Database runs well and is accessible with the password and username ...
In my manage.py I do next: `"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "standAlone.myScript"`

This is my error:  `raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.`

Comment: Please post the traceback. I guess you get the exception before you call settings.configure(). Try to add "assert 0" just before settings.configure or look carefully at the traceback.

Comment: @guettli what do you mean?! I do not know what you mean. I call it wrong?

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` is a tuple. Change it to `INSTALLED_APPS     = ('myApp',)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Django 1.2, the `DATABASE_*` family of settings was deprecated in favor of the new `DATABASES` setting. In 1.4 it was completely removed which means from 1.4 onwards you *have* to use the `DATABASES` setting.

See the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#id1

**Update:**
Just rewrite

```
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    DATABASE_NAME      = 'Test',
    DATABASE_USER      = 'root',
    DATABASE_PASSWORD  = 'testpw',
    DATABASE_HOST      = '/var/run/mysql',
    DATABASE_PORT      = '3306',
```

to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'testpw',
        'HOST': '/var/run/mysql',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and you're set.

**Update:**
Just as a side note, instead of trying to use `settings.configure` in your commandline scripts, the recommended way to run batch jobs is to create [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/). That way you don't have to duplicate your settings or mess with the environment and as the settings are loaded using the same mechanism as your regular web application, you are guaranteed they will be the same.

Comment: I suggest a change in Django is not wrong. Only now my question is how do I solve this? Do read the links but do not see what I should do to solve it. Thank you for your help already!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comprehensive solution! Only now have the same error ... Actually I am not so much with progress.
I only setting.py adapted, not myScript.py

Comment: Of course, `settings.configure` expects the same settings as you would write in your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. That means, if the `settings.py` file won't accept `DATABASE_*` settings and requires you to set the `DATABASE` dictionary, so does `settings.configure`. Also, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the settings.py file updated with proper database configuration and try python manage.py syncdb and check for errors if any